# symfony2 configure service with data from another service

Tags: symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

Is it possible in Symfony2 to configure a service by injecting data from another service? For example, by calling a getter on another service?

In my specific case I am creating a (reusable) service that can handle translatable entity fields. For this I need a list of available locales in the application. I have looked at some other bundles that also work with locales, but they always use a static array from the configuration. For example:

```
a2lix_translation_form:
    locales: [en, fr, nl]
```

This configuration usually ends up mapping to the service in the form of a constructor parameter or setter via the bundle configuration. For example:

```
class SomeService {
    function __construct(array $locales) { ... }
    // or
    function setLocales(array $locales) { ... }
}
```

But in my case the list of available locales is not always static and often comes from the database. I have created a `Locale` service in my application with a method `getLocales` that returns an array. But how do I get that array into my service that needs it?

The service I am creating that needs a list of locales is split off into a separate reusable bundle. I don't want to inject the `Locale` service directly because that service is specific to the application, and not the bundle I am creating. I want users of my bundle to be able to provide a static list of locales, or point towards a service that has all the locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this problem using [semantic configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) and [config defintions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html). It works pretty similar to how FOSUserBundle asks for a driver and uses different settings depending on your choice (orm, mongodb, propel).

You could add something like this to your config.yml:

```
a2lix_locale:
    provider: default # database
    # ... additional settings which are optional,
    # but required by provider, e.g. database settings
```

Your bundle's Configuration.php would verify that a valid provider was selected and that additional settings are set according to what each provider requires. Again, [FOSUserBundle provides a great example for how to do this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php).

Additionally in your bundle's MyBundleExtension.php in /DependencyInjection you can access the service container and pass for instance the parameter `locale` to your default service in order for it to use the application's default locale provided in parameters.yml.